# Can I install using Macports both py27 and py34 ports in the same location?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, macports

I've been using Python3.4 to complete certain tasks, though I still use Python2.7 as default.

I think I should be able to begin downloading py34 ports from using `sudo port install py34-whatever` in the same location as my Python2.7 ports.

However, I am running into significant downloading errors doing this.

Is it possible to download both py27 and py34 ports into the same location? Will there be problems doing this?

Comment: What kind of downloading errors do you get? This sounds more like a generic MacPorts problem. Installing multiple Pythons should not be a problem, as you can always switch via port select. In the case of Python 2 and 3, it should even be the case that they are directly accessible via python and python3 respectively

Comment: @MarcSchulder It appears you are correct.

Comment: I'll write an official answer to this then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems appear to be a generic Macports download problem. Resetting the download process via `sudo port clean <portname>` should help.

As to the general question of using multiple versions:

Macports allows you to install an arbitrary number of different versions in parallel. You switch between them using `port select --set <application> <portname>`, for example `sudo port select --set python python34`.
For easier access, you can define your own shell alias (e.g. `python3` or `python34`), pointing to `/opt/local/bin/python34`.

Answer (score 1):

My personal experience is that Anaconda makes these types of tasks painless. All the while providing the same functionality. http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install

Suppose you want an isolated environment for py27:

http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html#create-an-environment

```
conda create --name py27 python==2.7.10
```

To use the environment:

```
source activate py27
```

To install a package, conda install or pip install.

If you want a Python 3.4 environment just change the above command a bit. I have no affiliation with Anaconda, and I would guess other Python distros work just as well. This just made things easier for me, hope it does for others as well!

Comment: For a non-distro setup, I have found Homebrew installations pretty painless.